# Переход с C# на с++

Tags: c#, c++, linux, книги

Всем привет.

Я достаточно давно пишу на C#. Но тут появился очень интересный проект: написать асинхронного высокопроизводительного сетевого демона под linux.
Очень хочется за него взяться.

Последний раз я писал на C++ 15 лет назад. Почти ничего уже не помню.
Посмотрел что нового в C++ 14 и понял, учить C++ придется с нуля.
Подскажите книгу, а лучше видеокурс где описывается современный подход к разработке на C++ под linux ?

Comment: Очень не советую видеокурсы. А так — дубликат.

Comment: да, похоже дубликат. извините, не доглядел.

Comment: Может быть и дубликат, но именно асинхронность и многопоточность появилась в C++11. А большинство книг там будет про C++. Синтаксис самого языка топикастер знает. И опыт у него есть. Получается просто послали его.

Comment: @MaxZS ну вот не надо, Скотт Мейерс в последнем издании вполне себе учитывает особенности и 11-го и 14-го. Да и уверен, что многие хорошие книги переизданы с учетом последних нововведений. Не знаю как в C++, в .NET и C# это нормальная практика.

Comment: @rdorn ну так и что не надо? В чем проблема посоветовать эту книгу? Или он должен обделаться сначала перекачав и перечитав весь тот список? Это нормальная практика так вот делать?

Comment: не горячитесь. я оглавления читать умею. как раз маерса из этого списка выбрал. сижу раскуриваю...